# jQuery DOM attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following callback function when using the jQuery star plugin:

```
$('.star').rating({
    callback: function (value, link) {
        {
            if (response.session) {
                $.post("update.php", {
                    uid: response.session.uid,
                    mid: $('.star').attr('name'),
                    val: value
                });
                alert($('.star').attr('name'));

            }
        });
}
});
```

and the following html:

```
<input name="star2" type="radio" class="star"/>
<input name="star2" type="radio" class="star"/>
<input name="star2" type="radio" class="star" checked="checked"/>
<input name="star2" type="radio" class="star"/>
<input name="star2" type="radio" class="star"/>
```

how can I get the name from the jQuery? I tried doing .attr as above and it returns undefined. I tried doing `$($this).attr('name')` and it returns the jquery fancy box name..

Comment: @Yeameen that wouldn't work unless the rating plugin works in the event context (which I doubt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.star')
```

returns a **collection** of jQuery objects, so you should **iterate** it e.g.:

```
$('.star').each(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

the checked element is found by:

```
$('.star:checked').attr('name');
```

**update**, (in reply to comments) for multiple groups:

> what if I have two star rating sets

```
$('.star:checked').each(function () {
     alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: what if I have two star rating sets... how do I get the one the name of the star that is being clicked? my example above only shows one set of star ratings, while in reality in a page you can have more than 1 star ratings.. I want to know the name of the star that is clicked..

Comment: that will print all of the one that is checked right? but not necessarily the one that I clicked

Comment: If you click on it you do not have to evaluate the name here, you could get it inside the click-event-handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
var nameOfCheckedStar = $('.star:checked').attr('name');
```

I'm assuming you want the name of the checked star

Comment: I want to get the clicked name, not necessarily the checked one.. there can be multiple checked star rating

Comment: well since it's a radio group, the checked one will always be the one your clicked :)

Comment: As I mentioned above I can have multiple star rating with the same class, star... doing what you mentioned above will return the first set that is checked... even if I clicked on set-4, it will always return the 1st one

Comment: The behavior you want depends on your plugin. When does `callback` get called? Check the documentation, it should have access or some kind of context to the radio buttons. Since you're not working with an event bound on that DOM element, you can't get the context. The plugin needs to supply the context

Comment: as far as I know I can only get the value of the selected rating from the plugin. The callback is called when I click on the star

Comment: Why not just bind a click event handler on all your radio buttons and do your bit in there? `$('.star').click(function(){alert($(this).attr('name'));})` That should give you the name

Comment: you should be able to use `$(this).index()` to get the value if they are grouped.